# Emacs indent template class/functions

Tags: c++, templates, emacs

Does anybody know how to inhibit emacs from indenting the name of functions or classes after a template clause?

Currenty the result is:

```
template <typename T>
    class A {
    /* ... */
    };
```

where I would like to have:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
/* ... */
};
```

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT 1**
I'm using c++-mode with java as indent style for c++. I customized the c-offset-alist in this way:

```
(custom-set-variables 
;;
'(c-offsets-alist (quote ((case-label . +) (innamespace . 0))))
```

Comment: Have you written something in the .emacs?  I get the one you ask for by default.  I started emacs -Q.

Comment: @vpit3833 I edited the question to make the situation more clear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the `class` line and hit `TAB` to perform the (unsolicited) indentation.
Then press <kbd>Control-C</kbd><kbd>Control-O</kbd>`to display the indent mode for`topmost-intro-cont`

Press `ENTER`, then you can change the indent number (3 to 0 for instance).

At the end of your `.emacs` you can set permanently that instruction:

```
  (c-set-offset 'topmost-intro-cont 0 nil)
```

Comment: how do I press ^C^o? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are different styles for indentation for Emacs' C++ mode. [Quoting EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC):

A partial list of the better known C styles:

- “gnu”: The default style for GNU projects
- “k&r”: What Kernighan and Ritchie, the authors of C used in their book
- “bsd”: What BSD developers use, aka “Allman style” after Eric Allman.
- “stroustrup”: What Stroustrup, the author of C++ used in his book
- “linux”: What the Linux developers use for kernel development
- “python”: What Python developers use for extension modules
- “java”: The default style for java-mode (see below)
- “user”: When you want to define your own style

The `c-default-style` variable is what you need to change. Perhaps one of them will be what you need. Don't have Emacs right now, so I can't check them out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have already chosen the style *java* as indentation style for c++, and customized it for namespaces using `c-offsets-alist`. I would like to know if there is the possibility to do the same for templates

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I imagine your mode makes a difference.  In what mode are you editing? I assume c++-mode cause you have `c++` as a tag.

For me, in c++-mode, it turned out like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
   /* ... */
};
```

With the comments indented, but `class A` not indented.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different things to check:

I've seen similar issues when editing C++ .h files in C-mode instead of C++-mode.  By default, .h files are C-mode, not C++-mode.  [You can check this by looking for "C++" or "C" in parenthesis at the bottom of your window.]  You can setup emacs to always open .h files as C++ by using the following in your .emacs

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.h\\'"   . c++-mode)
                )
                  auto-mode-alist
                  ))
```

The other thing to check is how you have setup your c-default-style.  The info page for "CC Mode" goes into a lot more detail on all of the possibilities.